# python: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects (it should works!)

Tags: python, string, tuples

**I have a code:**

```
print "bug " + data[str.find(data,'%')+2:-1]
temp = data[str.find(data,'%')+2:-1]
time.sleep(1)
print "bug tuple " + tuple(temp.split(', '))
```

And after this my application displays:

> **bug 1, 2, 3** 
>   Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",
>   line 312, in RunScript
>       exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**   File "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\k.pawlowski\Desktop\atsserver.py",
>   line 165, in 
>       print "bug tuple " + tuple(temp.split(', ')) TypeError:
>   **cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple'
>   objects**

I don't know what I make wrong. *print tuple('1, 2, 3'.split(', '))* works properly.

Comment: When in doubt, test it in the interactive interpreter!!  `>>>` ftw!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
print tuple(something)
```

may work because print will do an implicit str() on the argument, but and expression like

```
"" + ()
```

does not work. The fact that you can print them individually doesn't make a difference, you can't concatenate a string and a tuple, you have to convert either one of them. I.e.

```
print "foo" + str(tuple("bar"))
```

However, depending on str() for conversion probably won't give the desired results. Join them neatly using a separator using ",".join for example

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think it should work?

try:

```
print "bug tuple " + str(tuple(temp.split(', ')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
print "bug tuple ", tuple(temp.split(', '))
```

Comment: this is it ;) thanks. I am stupid after many hours of coding.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why tuple by splitting, you have string for one ready except the paranthesis, why not:

```
print "bug tuple (%s)" % '1, 2, 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `tuple()`, following works,

```
outstr = str((w,t)) # (w,t) is my tuple
```